# Asterisk Instant Messaging and Video Conference

Tags: asterisk, instant-messaging, video-conferencing

We use Asterisk and Hard-Phones. Now we want to have Instant messaging on our Windows 7.0 and 8.0 PCs. Also we want to give them the ability to transfer files and have video conference.
We want our admin be able to manage permissions on these features.
Is it possible to integrate these features with Asterisk? If yes, what solutions do you offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sip message in asterisk, but it will be not so easy to maintain and debug.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+MessageSend

Better use independed [jabber](http://www.jabber.org/) message server on same host.

Video conference can be done via asterisk, but it is hard to setup and allow only one person speaking to be shown.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+video